# Processing: numbers that should be in sync aren't

Tags: processing

Here's my problem. I was working on making a program to count down to the next year in seconds or minutes (minutes to 1 decimal place, seconds to none) and I get this problem where the countdown is a bit out of sync with the system time. It isn't too much, only around half a second, but personally this bugs me a lot. I noticed this when I just looked at the clock on my computer, and, to be sure, I added a `System.out.println()` call to output the number on the countdown and the actual time. Here is my code:

```java
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

Calendar currentTime;
Calendar newYear;
int nextYear;
boolean isFullScreen = false;
boolean minutes = false;

void settings() {
  if(isFullScreen) {
    fullScreen();
  } else {
    size(500, 250);
  }
}
void setup() {
  frameRate(60);
}
void draw() {
  background(255, 0, 0);
  currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
  nextYear = currentTime.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 1;
  newYear = new GregorianCalendar(nextYear, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  fill(0);
  if(isFullScreen) {
    textSize(200);
  } else {
    textSize(50);
  }
  long timeInMillis = currentTime.getTimeInMillis();
  long newYearInMillis = newYear.getTimeInMillis();
  if(minutes) {
    text(String.valueOf((float)ceil((float)(newYearInMillis - timeInMillis)/6000)/10), width/2, height/2);
  } else {
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(ceil((float)(newYearInMillis - timeInMillis)/1000)) + ", " + currentTime.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    text(String.valueOf(ceil((float)(newYearInMillis - timeInMillis)/1000)), width/2, height/2);
  }
}
void mouseClicked() {
  minutes = !minutes;
}
```

I'm getting an output that doesn't make sense:

```
5666570, 10
5666570, 10
5666570, 10
5666570, 10
5666570, 10
5666570, 10
5666570, 10
5666570, 10
5666570, 10
5666570, 10
5666569, 10
5666569, 10
5666569, 10
5666569, 10
5666569, 10
5666569, 10
5666569, 10
5666569, 10
5666569, 10
5666569, 10
5666569, 10
5666569, 10
5666569, 10
5666569, 10
5666569, 10
5666569, 10
5666569, 10
5666569, 10
5666569, 10
5666569, 10
5666569, 10
5666569, 10
5666569, 10
5666569, 10
5666569, 10
5666569, 10
5666569, 10
5666569, 10
5666569, 11
5666569, 11
5666569, 11
5666569, 11
5666569, 11
5666569, 11
5666569, 11
5666569, 11
5666569, 11
5666569, 11
5666569, 11
5666569, 11
5666569, 11
5666569, 11
5666569, 11
5666569, 11
5666569, 11
5666569, 11
5666569, 11
5666569, 11
5666569, 11
5666569, 11
5666569, 11
5666569, 11
5666569, 11
```

Notice how the countdown thinks it should count down 28 frames before the actual time. Although this isn't huge, it is enough to be not only noticeable but to drive be nuts trying to figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't rely on `System.out.println()` for timing. It's much slower than other output, so it's normal for the print statements to lag behind the on-screen time.

That being said, the program is doing exactly what you're telling it to do- it's rounding the time **up** to the next second. This is why your on-screen time appears to be a half-second ahead of the real time.

Just stop using the `ceil()` function, and your time will sync up pretty closely with the system time:

```java
text(String.valueOf((newYearInMillis - timeInMillis)/1000), width/2, height/2);
```

Also, I'm not sure all of your logic is correct. For example, `GregorianCalendar` months are zero-based, so January should be 0, not 1.

Comment: My logic behind using the `ceil()` function was that it should change from 2 to 1 when the time remaining is 1.00. I think the easy way to fix this would be to just add 1 to the number passed to `String.valueOf()`, so like `text(String.valueOf((newYearInMillis - timeInMillis)/1000 + 1), width/2, height/2);` but that seems like a not-so-great way to fix it in my opinion. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @JustinBarker Adding 1 isn't guaranteed to work, since you can't guarantee exactly when your code is hit. Think about what you want to happen when you have exactly 1.0 seconds left, vs when you have 999 ms left. Honestly, if I were you, I'd abandon the time in millis and just use Processing's built-in time functions.

Comment: The reason I don't want to use Proessing's built in functions is because I would have to program in month lengths, leap years, etc.

Comment: also, I'm pretty sure that since getting rid of `(float)` will make it directly divide the `long` value by 1000, so it discards the remainder, so 1000/1000 = 1, +1 = 2, if there are 1000 milliseconds left, but 999/1000 = 0, +1 = 1. I think this isn't the best way to do it, because 1000 will give you 2 instead of 1, but I can't find a better way.

Comment: @JustinBarker Thinking about it more, I guess adding 1 is probably the way to go. The worst case scenario is that it's wrong for 1/60th of a second.

Comment: or, if I really wanted to, (which I don't right now but maybe later) use some logic to the affect of `if(newYearInMillis - timeInMillis % 1000 == 0) { ... }` but seriously it just doesn't seem worth it, and I have other things to do right now.

Comment: @JustinBarker Yeah, exactly. I'd suggest testing it with closer times (count down to the next minute, not the next year) and seeing how accurate it is.

Comment: Well, I did test it, but not that exact way. My two tests were: a) Set system time to 12/31/2015 23:59:00, and b) Search for a countdown to new year on the internet, both of which had the expected results. I guess I can try making it count to the next minute though, because it is easier than the other two.